# Client's PC not respecting CSS rule

Tags: microsoft-edge

[This page](http://sb.superiorit.com.au/medicalservices/ophthalmology/) has a UL with 3 LIs, each LI containing a contact name and details.

The following CSS applies:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    #medicalservices3 #tile li {
        width: 31.5%;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }
}
```

This rule is working well on my Edge & Chrome browsers on a desktop PC - I see a single row with 3 contacts.

However, on the problem Windows 10 PC, the rule is not being applied in Edge or Chrome. Instead the following rule applies:

```
@media (min-width: 640px) {
    #tile li {
        width: 47.5%;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }
}
```

- The screen width is probably around 1800px.

**EDIT** - the problem is affecting both Edge & Chrome. When they load the site, the site is loading the stylesheet as http://sb.superiorit.com.au/wp-content/themes/Divi-SBDS/style.css?ver=3.0.106

In this stylesheet on my PC on line 134 I see `#medicalservices3 #tile li`.

On the problem PC, when they load the stylesheet above in Chrome, `#medicalservices3 #tile li` is not present. I have cleared the Chrome cache.

However, the CSS rule above is present when viewing the stylesheet in Edge, yet it is still not applied in Edge.

Could their ISP be caching the CSS file above? **END EDIT**

Troubleshooting advice appreciated.
Steve

Comment: I have Windows 10 (my screen resolution is 1920x1080), and I've opened your page in Chrome and Edge. Everything is dysplayed as it supposed to be, `@media (min-width: 800px)` rule was picked up and I see three `li`'s in a row. Have they tried to open this page in private mode?

Comment: No, @htshame, I will put that on my list of things to try.

Comment: Just FYI, I also see the `@media (min-width: 640px)` rule, but it's being overridden by `@media (min-width: 800px)` rule. Also, just to take a wild stab in the dark, if their ISP has multiple servers from which it hosts the site, it's possible, however unlikely, that some servers have updated version of your CSS, and some don't.

Comment: Are your PC and the problematic PCs located in the same network? If not, i would bet for an intermediary caching proxies or a reverse cache. Best workaround: change the version number of your file.

Comment: Hi @SylvainBiehler, removing the version number / query string from the stylesheet URL resolved the problem. Add an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely:
- the problematic PCs and yours are not on the same network
- there is an intermediary caching proxies or a reverse cache on the problematic network
- you changed the content of the css file without changing the version number

-> update the version number of the file and everything should work fine